# Database modeling, user, moderator, admin

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a 3 type of users (users, moderator, admin).
And specific data for all 3 (users have name, admins have phonenumbers...)

My solution for roles, is two have one table "Users"(id, name...), one table "Roles" (id roles, name...) and one xref table usersXrefRoles (join table)(IDusers, IdRoles)
but that is NOT solution for the part "all 3 table have different fields", in other words do I must have 3 separate tables (users, moderator, admin) , or some kind of inheritance ?

What is the best practice for this kind od problem ?

Comment: Are the fields really that different? If they're not that different just put them all in one table and leave the ones you don't need blank. The 'best practice' is dictated by other constraints like for example how many other tables need to refer to the user table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just three types of roles, you could have something as simple as single user table with a `role` column, that would hold an enum value (or `role_id` column that would hold a reference to a role table - if there is any need for that).

If you would have different fields for each user type, you could use other tables and do [table subclassing](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=subclass.php) but it would be nice to tell what kind of fields. Maybe there is a better way to do what you want.

Also, read about [RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) and [ACLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) as alternatives to static roles. Many popular frameworks come with built-in support or extensions for such solution.

Comment: Thx for quick answer, users have name, phone, city,
moderators have last sign In date, category (fk)...
Admins have products etc. so the fields are quite different.
I took your advice, and subclassing is very much what I need.
thx again

Comment: @TestAndSet I would strongly advise you to just have one user table and all the described columns to apply to all users. Products will have only "user_id" that belongs to an admin, and users that do not apply to a category would have a "null" category. Subclassing will complicate your application and will make it much harder to "promote" a user to become an administrator or moderator.

Answer (score 0):

sub classing.   You should have three tables, but they should be Users (with userId, name, and other fields common to all users) Every users should be in this table, including the moderator and admins. Then have two other tables with the same PK value for the users who are moderators, and the users who are admins, with the data fields specific to those roles.